# Can't catch the exception when I send a REST request to an offline HTTP server

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, httpresponse

In my REST application I use this class to send requests:

```
public final class Utility {

private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

private Utility(){
}

public static <T> Response sendRequest(String URI, String method, T payload){
    Response response = null;
    WebTarget target = client.target(URI);
    switch(method){
    case "GET": 
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").get();
        break;
    case "POST":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").post(Entity.json(payload));
        break;
    case "PUT":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").put(Entity.json(payload));
        break;
    case "DELETE":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").delete();
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotAllowedException("Invalid method type was given "
                + "to the Utility.sendRequest() method");
    }

    if(response == null){
        throw new UnavailableServerException("The server at (" + URI + ") did not respond.");

    }

    return response;
}
}
```

I have recently had the idea that I want to handle cases when I send a request to an endpoint, which cant respond. (I didn't start the grizzly http server for it). I learned that if I try to send a request to an endpoint like this, my general ExceptionMapper (which implements ExceptionMapper(Exception)) catches it, and the exception was a NullPointerException (NPE).

So I figured all I have to do is just outsource the Response to a variable, and check if it's == null before returning it. With printfs and debug mode, I saw the following behaviour:

- Even for the failed request, `response == null` is not true.
- The failed request does get to the `return response` line, but the very next line in my resource method is not executed, exception happens.
- I tried to catch the NPE (even with `catch(Exception e)`) with try-catch blocks inside the Utility class, and inside the resource method too, with no succes.

I've tried to find out what throws NPE in the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response;` documentation -> no success. I'm out of ideas :/ (Btw `UnavailableServerException` is my custom exception also.)

Also what's the proper way to check is the request was successful, since the null check obviously not a good solution.

**EDIT: here is the stacktrace**

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:264)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.put(JerseyInvocation.java:326)
at eu.arrowhead.common.Utility.sendRequest(Utility.java:32)
at eu.arrowhead.core.gatekeeper.GatekeeperResource.GSDPoll(GatekeeperResource.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.setOutboundHeaders(HttpUrlConnector.java:421)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.access$100(HttpUrlConnector.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:384)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:262)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.commitStream(OutboundMessageContext.java:816)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:545)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
... 37 more
```

**EDIT2:**

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

@Override
public Response toResponse(Exception ex) {
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage("Class: " + ex.getClass().toString() + 
            " Message: " + ex.getMessage(), 500, "No documentation yet.");
    return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .entity(errorMessage)
            .build();
}

}
```

Here is my generic exception mapper too, although I do think this is not part of the problem, rather than the fact that that in my example my request involves 3 servers. This request is sent to an online server, which sends something to a 2nd online server (using the same utility class method), which polls a 3rd, which is offline in my test. The 2nd server cathes the ProcessingException  (which far as I know can be the okay response if the 3rd server is offline) and sends back my custom exception. but then at the 1st server somehow cant send this same exception back to my Postman client, and a generic NPE is thrown.

I'm gonna try to find the reason for that tomorrow though. I'll also update jersey from 2.22.1 to 2.23.1.

Comment: try to put your code inside the `try catch` block. I think when server is not available, HttpException is thrown.

Comment: Please show the actual stacktrace

Comment: I cant really show a stacktrace sadly. Even when I unregister my generic exception mapper, the only thing I get back in postman is the Grizzly html page, I think something there masks the stacktrace. @Valijon I have already tried this, like I mentioned in the post, no idea why doesnt it work.

Comment: Can you show us your `ExceptionMapper`? Maybe the problem is there. As you see, exception is identified (`ProcessingException`), maybe your `ExceptionMapper` is not configured correctly and throws you NPE.

Comment: added it in the 2nd edit

Answer (score 1):

The response shouldn't be null. Just like visiting a page through the browser when it doesn't exist, you should get some server error. Check the response.getStatus() for something in the 400's

You might also try putting in some sensible timeouts.

```
public static <T> Response sendRequest(String URI, String method, T payload){
try{
    ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
    configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
    configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 10000);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);

    Response response = null;
    WebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromUri(URI).build())
    switch(method){
    case "GET": 
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").get();
        break;
    case "POST":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").post(Entity.json(payload));
        break;
    case "PUT":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").put(Entity.json(payload));
        break;
    case "DELETE":
        response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").delete();
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotAllowedException("Invalid method type was given "
                + "to the Utility.sendRequest() method");
    }

    if(response.getStatus() != 200){  //200 OK!
        throw new UnavailableServerException("The server at (" + URI + ") did not respond.");
    }
    return response;
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've put `try catch` block and got `ProcessingException`

```
ScopedJaxrsResponse{ClientResponse{method=GET, uri=http://google.com/, status=200, reason=OK}}
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: foo.bar
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:652)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:291)
    at foo.Utility.sendRequest(Utility.java:32)
    at foo.Utility.a(Utility.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: foo.bar
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:203)
    ... 35 more
```

Junit error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The server at (http://foo.bar/) did not respond.
    at foo.Utility.sendRequest(Utility.java:53)
    at foo.Utility.a(Utility.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.junit.Test;

public final class Utility {

    private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    public Utility() {

    }

    @Test
    public void a() {
        System.out.println(Utility.sendRequest("http://google.com/", "GET", ""));
        System.out.println(Utility.sendRequest("http://foo.bar/", "GET", ""));
    }

    public static <T> Response sendRequest(String URI, String method, T payload) {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            WebTarget target = client.target(URI);
            switch (method) {
            case "GET":
                response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").get();
                break;
            case "POST":
                response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").post(Entity.json(payload));
                break;
            case "PUT":
                response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").put(Entity.json(payload));
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                response = target.request().header("Content-type", "application/json").delete();
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotAllowedException("Invalid method type was given " + "to the Utility.sendRequest() method");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = null;
        }

        if (response == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The server at (" + URI + ") did not respond.");

        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: i forgot i can get the stacktrace like this. see my edit

Comment: btw in Postman it still shows a frikin NPE, when I have my try-catch block and the if statement after it set up, just like yours. how is that possible?

Comment: what is your Jax-RS version?

Comment: My setup was: request -> receiver sends another request to the offline server. I checked, my custom exception is thrown at the receiver, but it does not get back to the original requester yet. But I think i can figure it out how to get around that. (jersey version 2.22.1 btw)

Comment: create new client each request and you will not get this error. Seems this fixed error: [https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2728](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2728)

Comment: I moved the client declaration inside the try block, didn't change the stacktrace.